# get values on a separated range object

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Is there a better way to get a separated range values in to a variant than a loop?

```
Dim vntValues As Variant  
Set rg = Range("$D$3:$D$7,$D$9:$D$21")  
vntValues = rg.Value  
Debug.Print UBound(vntValues)
```

the output is 5, while I think 18 is correct.

Comment: `rg.Value` will only return the values of the first `Area` within `rg`, i.e. it defaults to `vntValues = rg.Areas(1).Value`.  If you were to say `vntValues = rg.Areas(2).Value` then `UBound(vntValues)` would be 13.

Comment: What are you doing with `vntValues`?  If you're moving values, over-selecting the source and sparsely selecting the target works just fine: `Range("D3:D7,D9:D21").Value = Range("E3:E21").Value` doesn't overwrite `D8`.

Comment: You should just use a loop: abstract it out into a function if you don't want it cluttering up your main code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rg = Range("$D$3:$D$7,$D$9:$D$21")

For Each rng2 In rg.Areas
    vntValues = rng2.Value2
    Debug.Print UBound(vntValues)
Next
```